# Jmeter install fails

Tags: jmeter

On mac OS X trying to install jmeter have java8 (oracle) installed but the GUI never works.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Below is the stack trace

```
2019-10-10 09:57:11,487 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:187) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:139) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.jmeter.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:375) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:544) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
```

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you're using [DisplayLink](https://www.displaylink.com/)? If yes, you might be suffering from the following issue: [Java Apps crash on launch if connected to external DisplayLink device](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66114)

As per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/)

> **Java**  - use the [latest 64-bit version of Java SE JDK or Server JRE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=BM_Blog&utm_campaign=OOMFailure) where possible

So if you need to stick to Java 8 - try updating to [Java SE Development Kit 8u221](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (or use later versions, [Java 13](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html) is out already)

If nothing helps - you will either have to stop using this DisplayLink stuff or consider creating JMeter test using alternative approaches, i.e. via [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config) declarative YAML syntax.

Comment: this is perfect and exactly what it was... disconnecting from display link it works perfectly